# Factorial multiplied by the number itself

Tags: javascript, factorial

Apart from doing the factorial recursively,how could we  solve using the for loop?

```
function factorial(num){
for(var i=num;i>0;i--){
num*=i
}
return num;
}
factorial(3);
//18
```

answer should be 6 but prints 18

when I run this code say for any number x,the factorial result is again multiplied by x.
factorial(3) gives 6*3...
factorial(5) gives 120*5.What could be the problem?.Thanks

Comment: does [this](https://www.natashatherobot.com/factorials-javascript-recursion/) help?

Comment: if you change the line to `for(var i = (num - 1); i > 0; i--) {` it works.  also, factorial(0) = 1, so you'll need an if/else statement to sort this out. (`if(num === 0){ return 1} else { [for loop]}`) It doesn't cope with negative numbers either, which will need sorting out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already the value of num as result and you multiply it again with this value. You could start the iteration with the next smaller value and iterate as you already do.

```js
function factorial(num) {
    for (var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        num *= i;
    }
    return num;
}
console.log(factorial(3));
```

With a `while` loop, and a shorter comparison with a prefix decrement.

```js
function factorial(num) {
    var i = num;
    while (--i) {
        num *= i;
    }
    return num;
}
console.log(factorial(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

you are multiplying with the same number twice as you are initializing i with num, use i=num-1 like this:

```
function factorial(num){
  for(var i=num-1;i>0;i--){
  num*=i
}
  return num;
}
factorial(3)
```

Comment: add some explanation

Comment: @brk  You should start the iteration with the next smaller value as you have already assigned the num with number.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiplied the number with itself, this need not to be done.
Only required to multiply with numbers less then the given number to get the factorial.

Below is the code snippet for the same:

```
function factorial(num){
    for(var i=num-1;i>0;i--){
       num*=i
    }
    return num;
}
factorial(3);
```